# How to read two text and insert into a single field in db

Tags: java, mysql

I am working in Java. I have two TextField objects t22 and t23. My requirement is as follows:
I have to read the string from both the text fields, add a space in between both of the string values, and insert it into a single field in the mysql database.

I tried the following query, but, space is not appearing in the db.

```
stat.executeUpdate("insert into tmpnursetab (name) values ('"+t22.getText()+"' '"+t23.getText()+"')");
```

Please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
stat.executeUpdate("insert into tmpnursetab (name) values ('"+t22.getText()+" "+t23.getText()+"')");
```

Comment: I have got one more question. Now that I have inserted the value like you said about, will it be possible to add a new column to a table with the column name as the one we read using the above command?

stat.executeUpdate("alter table scheduletab add "+t22.getText()+" "+t23.getText()+" varchar(40)");
What is wrong here?

Comment: You probably dont want a space in your column name, im not even sure you can. Replace the space with an underscore (_)

Answer (score 4):

why not concatenate in java first before passing it to the query?

```
String _value = t22.getText() + " " + t23.getText()
stat.executeUpdate("insert into tmpnursetab (name) values ('" + _value + "')");
```

but the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Better use `PreparedStatements`

- [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

example of Prepared Statement.

```
String _value = t22.getText() + " " + t23.getText()
String _query = "insert into tmpnursetab (name) values (?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(_query);
pstmt.setString(1, _value);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

use mysql concat `select CONCAT('TEST1' , ' ', 'test2');`

```
insert into tmpnursetab (name) values (CONCAT('TEST1' , ' ', 'test2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
stat.executeUpdate("insert into tmpnursetab (name) values ('"+t22.getText()+" "+t23.getText()+"')");
```

or on Oracle DB:

```
stat.executeUpdate("insert into tmpnursetab (name) values ('"+t22.getText()+"'|| '"+t23.getText()+"')");
```

Comment: I have got one more question. Now that I have inserted the value like you said about, will it be possible to add a new column to a table with the column name as the one we read using the above command? 

stat.executeUpdate("alter table scheduletab add "+t22.getText()+" "+t23.getText()+" varchar(40)"); 

What is wrong here?

Comment: No, since column names are not allowed to have spacings.

Comment: Then, will it be possible to replace the space with an underscore character with the same query ?

Comment: As cowls already pointed out - yes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523298/how-to-read-two-text-and-insert-into-a-single-field-in-db/14523534#comment20250294_14523328